# create table with sticky head

Tags: 6, theming

how can I create table with sticky head.
I try [theme_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_table/6) but it output a simple table without floating head.

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In drupal 6, table will have sticky header by default. I did not see this because my table has few rows and my site has not any scroll :). its described on API: [theme_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_table/6)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
/* Make table headers stick to the top */

/* Put tables inside two divs */
var tables = $("table");
tables.each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var container = $("<div class='table-container'></div>");
    container.append($(this));
    parent.append(container);
});

var inners = $(".table-container");
inners.each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var container = $("<div class='outer'></div>");
    container.append($(this));
    parent.append(container);
});

var widths = new Array();

//create array of <th> widths
var i = 0;
$('tbody tr:first td').each(function () {
    widths[i] = $(this).width();
    i++;
});

// Make th have same size as td
i = 0;
$('thead > tr > th').each(function(){
    $(this).width(widths[i] + 1);
    i++;
})


/* ------------- Reposition the thead so it won't overlap -----------------*/
var h = 0;
// Move the thead up. 
$('thead').each(function(){
    h =$(this).height();
    $(this).css('top', -$(this).height() + 1)
})

 //Now move the whole table down same distance
$('.outer').each(function(){
     $(this).css('top', h);
})
```

And then add this css:

```
/*----------------Sticky Headers ---------------------*/
```

.outer{
  position:relative;
}

.table-container{
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding-right: 1px;
}

.outer thead{
  position:absolute;
}

Important: Remember to set a max height for your tables so you can see it working.
Note: this method won't make it stick to the top of the browser, but into its container div.